# Laravel collection contains

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I'm using the Laravel `contains` method on a collection https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains. But it does not work for me.

```
foreach ($this->options as $option) {
    if($options->contains($option->id)) {
        dd('test');
    }
}
```

`dd($options);` looks like this:

```
Collection {#390
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
      0 => array:7 [
        "id" => 10
        "slug" => "test"
        "name" => "test"
        "poll_id" => 4
        "created_at" => "2016-11-12 20:42:42"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-12 20:42:42"
        "votes" => []
      ]
      1 => array:7 [
        "id" => 11
        "slug" => "test-1"
        "name" => "test"
        "poll_id" => 4
        "created_at" => "2016-11-12 20:42:42"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-12 20:42:42"
        "votes" => []
      ]
      2 => array:7 [
        "id" => 12
        "slug" => "test-2"
        "name" => "test"
        "poll_id" => 4
        "created_at" => "2016-11-12 20:42:42"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-12 20:42:42"
        "votes" => []
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

Result of `dd($option->id);` is `10`.

What could be wrong? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Somehow, more than 5 years later, nobody has correctly answered this question. The output from `dd()` clearly shows the collection contains a single item: an array. Of course attempting to use `Collection::contains()` on an array will fail!

Comment: And even if the accepted answer worked, it is just asking "does this collection have an id equal to its own id?" Of course it does! I feel like I'm taking crazy pills, etc.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should pass a key / value pair to the contains method, which will
determine if the given pair exists in the collection. Use [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains) method in this way:

```
foreach ($this->options as $option) {
  // Pass key inside contains method
  if($option->contains('id', $option->id)) {
      dd('test');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Use the following, which tells Laravel you want to match the 'id':

```
$options->contains('id', $option->id);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains)

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($this->options as $option) {
    if(!$options->flatten(1)->where('id',$option->id)->isEmpty()) {
        dd('test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `contains` method determines whether the collection contains a given item.
There are basically three ways in which it can be used :

- simply checking the item

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Sarah', 'age' => 23]);

$collection->contains('Desk');

// false

$collection->contains('Sarah');

// true
```

- checking the key/value pair :

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Sarah', 'age' => 23],
    ['name' => 'Vicky', 'age' => 34],
]);

$collection->contains('name', 'Hank');

// false
```

- checking via callback function :

```
$collection = collect([3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);

$collection->contains(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value < 2;
});

// false
```

Now, for your problem, we will use the second category, i.e :

```
foreach ($this->options as $option) {
   // here id is key and $option->id is value
  if($option->contains('id', $option->id)) {
      dd('test');
  }
}
```

Link to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#:%7E:text=George%27%2C%20%27age%27%20%3D%3E%2029%5D-,contains(),-The)

Comment: This is literally the exact answer that was posted > 5 years ago.