# How to check if collection's column matches an array

Tags: laravel

- Model `CustomerDocuments` holds customer docs, `doc_id` is a column in this model that signifies which document is there.
- I have an array of needed document IDs, say `$neededDocs = [1,2,3]`.

How do I check if my collection `CustomerDocuments` contains `$neededDocs` in each item of this collection.

if all `$neededDocs`are present in each CustomerDocuments.doc_id then return true, else, false.

I would like to preform this with collection->contains as follows:

```
CustomersDocuments::where('customer_id', $customer->id)
    ->contains('doc_id',$required_onboarding_docs)
    ->get();
```

Yet this syntax is wrong

Comment: Do you want to check if each row's `doc_id` is present in `$neededDocs`?

Comment: @erezt Please refer to this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566972/laravel-collection-contains

Comment: @Mozammil, yes.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin I saw the `foreach` there, I was hoping to avoid it since the whole purpose collection methods is the ability to run over them without an additional foreach, thanks for the link anyhows.

Comment: I am confused. I got the impression that you wanted to check that your customer documents result comprises of the documents you specified in `$neededDocs`. I updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could probably achieve this with something like the following:

```
$documents = CustomersDocuments::where('customer_id', $customer->id)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('doc_id')
    ->toArray();
```

The above will output an array with all the `doc_id`.

```
return $documents == $neededDocs;
```

You could then just compare it with your `$neededDocs` array.

**Edit**: If you, however, want to check that each row in your collection contains a `doc_id` that is present in `$neededDocs`, you could do it like this:

```
$collection = CustomersDocuments::where('customer_id', $customer->id)->get(); 

return $collection->contains(function($value, $key) use ($neededDocs) {
    return in_array($value->doc_id, $neededDocs); 
});
```

I am not entirely sure which one you want, but these should do the trick.

Comment: Mozammil, thanks for effort, the new edit returns `true` as the number of items in array (not good). But I went with your first answer, comparing arrays... not elegent but it works :)

Comment: The second case addresses a totally different use case. In the first case, we are checking if your result is equal to what you need. In the second case, we are checking if each row is actually a document you need. It may have hundreds of documents.